# Change edges/triangulation of plane geometry

Tags: three.js

I am trying to edit the edges/triangulation of a planebuffer geometry in three js.

[Example of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzGyR.png)

I want to change the corners in red to be triangulated like the corner in green.

Is this possible via editing a plane, or do I have to start building my own custom mesh buffer.

Here is a fiddle for an example of the kind of manipulation I am doing on the plane. (can click and drag to rotate it)

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;
var geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
    camera.position.z = 5;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 10, 10, 10, 10 );
    const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 1);
    const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.1);
    pointLight.position.y += 2;
    pointLight.position.x = -1;
    scene.add(pointLight);
    scene.add(ambientLight);
    
    const grid = [
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
      [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
      [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0],
      [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0],
      [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0],
      [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0],
      [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0],
      [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
      [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ];


    const planePos = geometry.attributes.position;

    for (let x = 0; x < grid.length; x++) {
      const row = grid[x];
      for (let y = 0; y < row.length; y++) {
        const h = row[y];
        const i = (x * row.length) + y;
        planePos.setZ(i, h * 0.5);
      }
    }
        
        //
        
    material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({flatShading:true});

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.rotateX(Math.PI * -0.5);
    mesh.translateZ(-1);
    scene.add( mesh );
        
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        
        var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

}

function animate(t) {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: `PlaneGeometry` is an indexed `BufferGeometry`, so instead of creating your own geometry, modify `.index` of the existing one.

Comment: @prisoner849 Thank you, I console logged out the contents of indexes, and that makes some sense.

I'll post my own soloution in a bit if I find one.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as @prisoner849 commented, buffergeometryies index property was the answer.

I redid the triangulation of the mesh by looping over the "squares" of my mesh, getting their corners and then changing the indexes for each squares triangles to one of a pre calculated set, based on which corner had a unique height. It also seems that you want the indexes to go in a specific order to control which side is "up", it seems to be that counter clockwise  or so.

```js
const size = 10;
const vertMap = [0, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1];
const triSets = [
  [0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 1],
  [1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3],
  [0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 1],
  [1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3],
];

const getSquareVerts = (x, y) => {
  const i = (y * size) + x + y;
  return [i, i + 1, i + (size + 2), i + (size + 1)];
}

const getUniqueHeightPoint = (verts) => {
  let unique = -1;
  const set = verts.reduce((p, n) => {
    const c = p[n.toString()] || 0;
    p[n.toString()] = c + 1;
    return p;
  }, {});
  const keys = Object.keys(set);
  if (keys.length == 2 && (set[keys[0]] == 1 || set[keys[0]] == 3)) {
    for (const key of keys) {
      if (set[key] == 1) {
        unique = verts.findIndex((v) => v == parseFloat(key));
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return unique;
}

const reworkTris = (plane) => {
  let indexOffset = 0;
  const planeIdx = plane.geometry.index;
  for (let y = 0; y < this.size; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < this.size; x++) {
      const verts = this.getSquareVerts(x, y);
      const heights = verts.map((v) => this.planePos.getZ(v));
      const uniqueHeight = this.getUniqueHeightPoint(heights);
      let tris = vertMap.map((i) => verts[i]);
      if (uniqueHeight >= 0) {
        tris = triSets[uniqueHeight].map((i) => verts[i]);
      }
      planeIdx.set(tris, indexOffset);
      indexOffset += 6;
    }
  }
  planeIdx.needsUpdate = true;
}

const plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry());
reqorkTris(plane);
```